# MySQL select random com prioridades

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-select, random

Tenho o seguinte cenário, possuo uma tabela e preciso fazer um select com um order by RAND(). Porém eu gostaria de colocar algumas condições por exemplo:

```
TABELA
ID | NOME | IDADE | GRUPO
```

> Dados

```
1 | Hiago | 20 | 1
2 | Igor | 15| 1
3 | Ana| 18 | 2
4 | Fernanda| 19 | 4
5 | João | 20 | 5
5 | Tati | 16 | 2
```

Gostaria de fazer um `SELECT` com o `ORDER BY RAND()` mas nesse `SELECT` eu iria colocar um LIMIT de 3 e eu gostaria de garantir que nesses 3 tenham valores da coluna `GRUPO` repetidos só caso não possua mais registros destintos na coluna `GRUPO`.

**Oque deve acontecer**

RETORNO (CORRETO) COM LIMIT 3:

```
2 | Igor | 15| 1
3 | Ana| 18 | 2
4 | Fernanda| 19 | 4
```

RETORNO (INCORRETO) COM LIMIT 3:

```
1 | Hiago | 20 | 1
2 | Igor | 15| 1
4 | Fernanda| 19 | 4
```

> O retorno acima foi incorreto porque ele repetiu o grupo 1 2 vezes sendo que haviam os grupos 2, 4 e 5 ainda para serem exibidos.

RETORNO (CORRETO) COM LIMIT 5:

```
2 | Igor | 15| 1
3 | Ana| 18 | 2
4 | Fernanda| 19 | 4
5 | João | 20 | 5
1 | Hiago | 20 | 1
```

> Nesse caso foi correto porque todos os grupos já apareceram pelo menos uma vez então ele repetiu o código do grupo 1, mas nada impediria dele repetir o 2 já que todos apareceram...

Então vamos a pergunta, como eu montaria esse SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o mais fácil neste caso seria usar um procedure e fazer um loop sorteando cada linha com as condições. Mas consegui pensar em um jeito de fazer as consultas sem isso.

Comandos MySQL para criar a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS random_prioridade (
  id int NOT NULL,
  nome varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  idade int NOT NULL,
  grupo int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO random_prioridade (id, nome, idade, grupo) VALUES
(1, 'Hiago', 20, 1),
(2, 'Igor', 15, 1),
(3, 'Ana', 18, 2),
(4, 'Fernanda', 19, 4),
(5, 'João', 20, 5),
(6, 'Tati', 16, 2);
```

No seu Tati está com id 5, troquei por 6 para não ter nenhum id repetido.

Consulta para LIMIT 3:

```
SELECT rp.id, rp.nome, rp.idade, rp.grupo
FROM random_prioridade rp, 
( SELECT a.id as id0, b.id as id1, c.id as id2
  FROM random_prioridade a, random_prioridade b, random_prioridade c
  WHERE a.id < b.id AND b.id < c.id
  ORDER BY ( cast(a.grupo=b.grupo as int) + cast(a.grupo=c.grupo as int) + 
             cast(b.grupo=c.grupo as int) ), rand()
  LIMIT 1
) selecionados 
WHERE rp.id IN (selecionados.id0, selecionados.id1, selecionados.id2)
ORDER BY rand()
```

Consulta para LIMIT 5:

```
SELECT rp.id, rp.nome, rp.idade, rp.grupo
FROM random_prioridade rp, 
( SELECT a.id as id0, b.id as id1, c.id as id2, d.id as id3, e.id as id4
  FROM random_prioridade a, random_prioridade b, random_prioridade c, random_prioridade d, random_prioridade e
  WHERE a.id < b.id AND b.id < c.id AND c.id < d.id AND d.id < e.id
  ORDER BY ( cast(a.grupo=b.grupo as int) + cast(a.grupo=c.grupo as int) + cast(a.grupo=d.grupo as int) + 
             cast(a.grupo=e.grupo as int) + cast(b.grupo=c.grupo as int) + cast(b.grupo=d.grupo as int) + 
             cast(b.grupo=e.grupo as int) + cast(c.grupo=d.grupo as int) + cast(c.grupo=e.grupo as int) +
             cast(d.grupo=e.grupo as int) ),  rand()
  LIMIT 1
) selecionados 
WHERE rp.id IN (selecionados.id0, selecionados.id1, selecionados.id2, selecionados.id3, selecionados.id4)
ORDER BY rand()
```

Pra fazer com outro número no LIMIT é só usar a mesma lógica. Mas acho que acima de 5 já fica inviável de escrever a consulta.